# M-dependency and ergodicity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Let $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a strictly stationnary m-dependent sequence of real-valued random variables on an underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, i.e. $X_n$ and $X_{n'}$ are independent if $\vert n-n' \vert\geq m$. Strictly stationnary here means that $\{X_n,n \in \mathbb{N}\} =\{X_{n+k},n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ in distribution for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This already implies that $X_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a measure-preserving dynamical system with respect to $\tau: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ with $X_{n+1}(\omega) = X_n(\tau(\omega))$. Can we also conclude ergodicity, i.e. that any $A \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\tau(A)=A$ is $\mathbb{P}$-trivial?

Answer (score 3):

I am fairly sure you can, though please do check the following for issues/errors. Take any $A$ in the invariant sigma algebra, and invoke the ergodic theorem on $1_A$.

Then, you would hope to get

$$\frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=0}^{mn} 1_A(X_n) \to 1_A$$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

Note that

$$\frac{1}{mn} \sum_{i=0}^{mn} 1_A(X_n) = \frac{1}{mn} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n} 1_A(X_{j + km}) \right) \to \mathbb{E} 1_A $$ as $n \to \infty$ as each of the subsequences $\{X_j + km\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d and therefore ergodic, which implies $A$ is trivial.

Comment: I don't think the equality of the sums is correct... And also the equality to the expectation.... It should converge for $n$ to $\infty$, no?

Comment: The equality of sums is just Fubini's; I am separating out the independent components basically; yeah, the equality there is in the limit as n goes to infinity (I will correct that typo), so uniqueness of the limit solves it; I will read over your proof to check it though

Comment: Thank you for your effort. mhm ok think I understand your approach (I think some indices are wrong and I guess it needs to be an expectation in the first equation). I don't understand though how you deduce that $A$ is trivial, $A$ is in general not in the invariant $\sigma$-algebra wrt to an iid sequence.

Comment: If 1_A = E 1_A = P(A), then P(A) is either 0 or 1, which means A is trivial!

Comment: The expectation in the first one is E[1_A | T] = 1_A, where we use the fact that A is in the invariant algebra T. For the second limit, I was basically trying to use the fact that for iid sequences the tail sigma algebra is trivial, so any expectation of any RV of it in the tail should be just the expectation. That is the part I am most unsure about, since it might be wrong? I think it is a similar measurability issue to your answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the proof of user "E-A" is correct, however I came up with another one (please feel free to check):
One knows that $X_{n+mj},j \in \mathbb{N}$ is i.i.d. for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$ be an invariant event, i.e. $\tau(A)=A$. Then we have that
$$ A \in \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots) \subset \sigma\bigg( \bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1} \bigcap_{n \geq 0} \sigma(X_{(n+k)m+j},k \geq 0) \bigg)   $$
Now for each $j=0,\ldots,m-1$ we can interpret $\mathcal{A}_j=\bigcap_{n \geq 0} \sigma(X_{(n+k)m+j},k \geq 0)$ as the terminal $\sigma$-algebra of an i.i.d. process and we have with Kolmogorov's $0$-$1$ law we conclude $\mathbb{P}(A') \in\{0,1\} $ for each element $A' \in \mathcal{A}_j$ for any $j=1,\ldots,m-1$. Since $A \in \sigma\big( \bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1} \mathcal{A}_j \big)$ we can write $A$ as a finite intersection/union of elements in $\bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1}\mathcal{A}_j$. We conclude $\mathbb{P}(A) \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: This was my first thought actually, but I don't think it is right to say that A is in the sigma algebra generated by some sets, so it has to be a finite intersection or union of these elements

Comment: I think it still works because we look at a $\sigma$-field which is generated by finitely many $\sigma$-fields. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but if I had to lean one way or another, I would lean that it is right. I think your proof is better than mine :)